# как сделать ActionBar на одном из активити,а на других убрать

Tags: android

Как можно сделать, чтобы в первом активити `ActionBar` был, а в других его не было?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы у `Activity` не было `ActionBar`, ей нужно выставить тему `NoActionbar` в `Manifest`.

---

Например: `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`.

Comment: А как сделать так что бы допустим в Activity_Registration ActionBara не было. А в Activity Login было?

Comment: Делайте две темы - одна с `ActionBar`, другая - без него

Comment: @Exe1ent, как написал Сергей — в манифесте объявляете две разные активности с разными темами.